# How to speed up this VBA code with slicers?

Tags: vba, excel, slicers

I have a spreadsheet with seven tables (tbl_1, tbl_2 ...tbl_7) each controlled by its own slicer. Each slicer has six buttons (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60) referring to Team Codes. I use the code below to select one team on every slicer, then create a PDF for each team / slicer setting. As of now, the code takes anywhere from 5-7min to run. Any help is much appreciated.

```
Sub SlicerTeam()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sc As SlicerCache
Dim si As SlicerItem

On Error GoTo errHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

For x = 1 To 6
    For i = 1 To 7
    Set sc = wb.SlicerCaches("tbl_" & i)
        sc.ClearAllFilters
        For Each si In sc.VisibleSlicerItems
            Set si = sc.SlicerItems(si.Name)
                If Not si Is Nothing Then
                    If si.Name = x * 10 Then
                        si.Selected = True
                    Else
                        si.Selected = False
                    End If
                Else
                    si.Selected = False
                End If
        Next si

    Next i
Call PDFCreate
Next x

exitHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub

errHandler:
MsgBox ("Error in updating slicer filters.")
Resume exitHandler

End Sub
```

Comment: If the code works and you are looking for ways to improve you should post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as it is too broad for this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that these slicers are slicing pivot tables, try the below code. It may help speed things up, depending on how big your PivotTables are.

```
Sub SlicerTeam()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sc As SlicerCache
Dim si As SlicerItem

dim pt as PivotTable

On Error GoTo errHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

For Each pt in wb.PivotTables
    pt.ManualUpdate = True
Next

For x = 1 To 6
    For i = 1 To 7
    Set sc = wb.SlicerCaches("tbl_" & i)
        sc.ClearAllFilters
        For Each si In sc.VisibleSlicerItems
            Set si = sc.SlicerItems(si.Name)
                If Not si Is Nothing Then
                    If si.Name = x * 10 Then
                        si.Selected = True
                    Else
                        si.Selected = False
                    End If
                Else
                    si.Selected = False
                End If
        Next si

    Next i

    For Each pt in wb.PivotTables
        pt.ManualUpdate = True
    Next


    Call PDFCreate
Next x

exitHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub

errHandler:
MsgBox ("Error in updating slicer filters.")
Resume exitHandler

End Sub
```

Comment: You can trim up that inner most block with 1 line: `si.Selected = True = si.Name = x * 10`. Also, won't `si.Selected = False` fail? Since `si = Nothing` in the outer If block?

Comment: After using Brandon's code (with Scott's additional contributions), the macro finishes around 23 seconds. Significantly faster than before!

Answer (score 0):

After several trials.. found this is the best option.

1. Disable calculations:

   ```
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   With Application
   .EnableEvents = False
   .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   End With
   ```
2. type code to Remove slicer conections.... example:

   ```
   ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Area").PivotTables.RemovePivotTable ( _
       ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotDatosGraficoAbsoluto"))
   ```
3. Set slicer value to true, and others to false... example:

   ```
   Set MySlicerCache = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Area")
               For i = 1 To MySlicerCache.SlicerItems.Count
                   With MySlicerCache.SlicerItems(i)
                       If .Name = "Comercial GJ" Then
                           .Selected = True
                           'Range("E1").Value = .Name
                       Else:
                           .Selected = False
                       End If
                   End With
               Next i
   ```
4. Do the Slicer conections.. example:

   ```
   ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Area").PivotTables.AddPivotTable ( _
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotDatosGraficoAbsoluto"))
   ```
5. Enable Events:

   ```
   With Application

     .EnableEvents = True

     .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   ```

   End With

This will save aprox 40% of waiting time